# PAM Module & nsswitch.conf

Tags: authentication, pam

As i know, there are two authentication schema available on linux.

1. PAM auth modules and,
2. /etc/nsswitch.conf file

When user logs in, which one take the precedence.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse nssswitch and PAM. It's not the same:

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` is a configuration file to configure, where the system should get it's databases. Databses for users, groups, passwords, dns lookups and so on. For example when you change the owner (`chown`) or the permissions (`chmod`) of a file. Then the system needs to know how the uids and gids should be interpreted; from the files (`/etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/group`) or from an LDAP server (or both) or from another service (NIS, AD, Kerberos). Also nsswitch-related is the priority in case of dublicate entries.

**PAM** is a component that defines, what at authentication, password change or session start should happen. PAM grants or denies the access. It mounts filesystem that needs to be mounted at a user login (`pam_mount.so`), execs login scripts (`pam_exec.so`), authenticates over unix method (`pam_unix.so`) or via LDAP (`pam_ldap.so`). It passes the password provided by the user from module to module and (however configured) the modules may break the stack or not. That ends in a successful or unsuccessful authentication.

Comment: Ok. Thats mean `nsswitch.conf` will not involve for user authentication by any means.? But my concern is then what this  comment of `passws   compat` in it's config(nsswitch.conf) stands for.?

Comment: nsswitch.conf provides the information which databaes should be used. And `compat` is there for historical reasons. See this link the **Compat mode** part: http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi/man?nsswitch.conf+5+NetBSD-1.4.3

Comment: Thanks a lot... it was great help to get rid of my confusion. Thanks again.